# Is there a way to combine "variable pointsize", with "ticlabels" in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to combine "variable pointsize" (for example), with
"ticlabels"?

The documentation says (in different places):

> Variable pointsize is always taken from the first additional column
>   provided in a using spec.  Variable color is always taken from the
>   last additional column.  When plotting with style linespoints it is
>   not currently possible to specify separate colors for the lines and
>   the points.  If all three properties are specified for each point, the
>   order of input data columns is thus

```
plot DATA using x:y:pointsize:pointtype:color \
    with points lc variable pt variable ps variable
```

Then elsewhere:

> Axis tick labels may be generated for any of the plot axes: x x2 y y2
>   z.  The ticlabels() specifiers must come after all of the
>   data coordinate specifiers in the using portion of the command.

I've tried without success a few different combinations.

```
gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 7
```

Is the order clearly documented someplace?  And if it isn't, what is the magic order, if any?

Comment: What does your code and data look like? What is the result and what should be the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use the following code with gnuplot 5.2.6

```
### variable pointsize, pointtype, color and ticlabels()
reset session

$Data <<EOD
one   1 1.1  5 0xff0000
two   2 2.2  7 0x00ff00
three 3 3.3  9 0x0000ff
four  4 4.4 11 0xffff00
five  5 5.5 13 0x00ffff
six   6 6.6 15 0xff00ff
EOD

plot $Data u 0:2:3:4:5:xtic(1) with points ps var pt var lc rgb var
### end of code
```

I get the following. Isn't this the result you want?

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed.  I'll send a note to the GNUPlot people about the documentation.  "Variable color is always taken from the last additional column." is misleading.  Thanks.  This example you have given should be in their demo directory, too.